# Which apache/mysql/php package is best for windows?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, coldfusion, web-server, lighttpd

I have tried appservnetwork, was the best so far, but I haven't seen them do an update in ages, EasyPHP is just slow to load always. Wamp and Xamp, all put in their description that is not for production.

I do not plan to host publicly this site or site's I am working on. But I do want a fast loading apache/mysql/php server for development purposes.

I used to really like WLMP, which is Lighttpd for Windows, but that project seems unupdated or abandoned.

I refuse to use IIS, but i have no desire to get into any wars over it.

I run windows xp sp3 at my home pc. I will need to have a web server setup for professional work, as well as some fun websites I am working on.

I just want it fast enough, so i can run it via localhost, and not take forever to load in the browser.

Thank you...

I plan mostly do php programming and perhaps coldfusion via this.

Comment: This is real amusing, 1st my topic is moved here, then it's closed. In either case I have no control and I get no voice. Thanks. And this is about selecting a version of apache to be installed on windows.

Answer (score 3):

I use [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) which includes :

- Apache 2.2.17
- php 5.3.5
- MySQL 5.5.8
- phpMyAdmin 3.3.9
- xDebug

Really easy to use and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linux virtual machine, Debian through VirtualBox for instance. This way you will have something really close to a real production web server, with a powerful command line interface.

If you use chef, you can generate a recipe with [this awesome tool](https://puphpet.com/)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with installing your own stack?

You can install:

- [The latest version of Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/)
- [The latest version of PHP](http://php.net/)
- [The latest version of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/)

Configuration is relatively easy and you have full control over what kind of setup you want. That way you can come as close to the production environment's configuration as possible... Of course, if your production server is on a POSIX compliant OS, you'll have to deal with case-sensitivity.

Comment: This is for windows use only, sorry.

Comment: @crosenblum: You can still install your own stack on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the absolute worst case you can download apache and php without any package software like XAMP, WAMP etc... However I have used XAMPP in production and there really isn't any issue, just make sure you set a root password for the database etc etc.

Comment: Security isn't my main concern, just perfrmance, so i can do work and test on my home/dev pc, before moving to production.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by your reference to Windows XP that you mean you'd like to install the AMP stack on Windows, my suggestion would be:

1. Pull down and run the Microsoft Web Platform Installer and use it to install PHP and MySQL- it can be found at: http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/
2. Then you can snag the latest Apache installer from the Apache.org site - http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

If that is still too much effort, I'd suggest pulling down the Acquia Drupal Dev Desktop down, which includes an entire DAMP stack and then some. Don't let the Drupal portion of it scare you off, you should be able to use this whether you're leveraging Drupal or not. It can be found at: http://network.acquia.com/documentation/acquia-drupal-stack

HTH

Comment: I've used the installer before, isn't it only for IIS usage? To add things to IIS?